# Невозможно извне подключиться к серверу

Tags: linux, сервер, порт

На компьютере с Linux запущен сервер на порте 25565. Раздача интернета происходит с Android, по Wi-Fi. К серверу никто не может подключиться, происходит `ConnectionTimeoutException`. Через `iptables` пробовал открывать порт, выключал фаервол. nmap до сих пор не находит открытых портов, подключаться могу только я, вместо IP прописав localhost.

Не понимаю - проблема как-то зависит от того, что сервер запущен из под Wi-Fi? Что мне делать?

Comment: Какой сервер? Какую сеть слушает? Ваш телефон - роутер, без рута не получится трафик перенаправить. И из какой сети хотите к "серверу" достучатся?

Comment: @Hellseher, однако получилось все без рута. Проблема в коннекте к телефону

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что связь идет через телефон. Изначально, андроид не поддерживает такое подключение, в обратную сторону запросто, а входящие соединения не маршрутизируются.
Решение описано в похожем [вопросе](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/168422/how-to-port-forward-internet-using-android-hotspot-to-pc).

Comment: Немного непонятно, получается, нужно не открывать порт, а просто его пробросить на другой? То есть нужно свой внешний IP и порт 25565 пробросить на локальный интерфейс с портом 80?

Comment: Не на локальный, а на адрес сервера. Правило вида "Все входящие на телефон соединения по порту 25565 отправлять на сервер с ип таким-то". И отдельно на телефоне разрешить принимать из-вне соединения по этому порту.

Comment: но ведь сервер запускается на IP телефона, разве нет?

Comment: Получается, что надо все соединения по порту 25565 слать на сервер, который тоже запущен на этом же IP с этим же портом?

Comment: Так как интернет раздается через wifi, то у каждого подключенного клиента (в т.ч. сервер) есть свой IP который ему присваивает телефон. Этот IP и надо вписывать в телефон. Если к телефону подключится несколько компьютеров, откуда телефону знать какой запрос кому перенаправлять?

Comment: так получается что 2ip врет? Он мне один и тот же IP показывает, что на телефоне, что на компьютере

Comment: Нет, не врет! Телефон преобразует адреса внутренней сети в один внешний адрес. Но это не значит, что все компьютеры что подключены к телефону имеют один этот адрес. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT

Comment: я понял, кажется, спасибо за NAT. Получается, что к моему серверу нужно подключаться через внешний IP телефона и порт 25565. А телефон надо настроить так, чтобы он слушал порт 25565 и пробрасывал сетевые запросы на IP адрес, который был присвоен компьютеру, на котором запущен сервер. Так?

Comment: Да! Именно так оно и работает.

Comment: ага. Ну, как узнать выданный компьютеру IP, это я найду. Но как я буду слушать порт, если он закрыт?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106164/discussion-between---and-morewind).

Answer (score 0):

Куплен хостинг. Собственно все